# Make Gitalist obey the permission settings of Gitolite?

Tags: git, permissions, gitolite

I am wondering if we can get both benefits of Gitalist and Gitolite. The former provides good web UI while the later provides flexible permission settings.

My first trial of setup Gitalist seems not to obey the permission settings (by Gitolite's hooks). Does anyone have any suggestion for that?

Answer (score 0):

You could adapt the recipe for gitweb described at http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/tips.html under "helping with gitweb".
The gist is: give read permission to a user named gitweb for the repositories you want to show. Then include a script in the gitweb script that asks gitolite if the user is allowed to read the requested repo.